# Spring social ProviderSignInController creates a session whereas we are using oauth2

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-social

We are using a JWT token as authentication mechanism. When we sign in using Google and Spring social, our /signin endpoint added by Spring social put a JSESSIONID as a cookie. I don't know how to disabled this behavior (that's the question).

As we are using an HTTP header as auth payload we don't need a CSRF protection. We don't want a cookie with a JSESSIONID payload, especially as we don't know the scope and rights of this cookie.

Here is social configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfiguration implements SocialConfigurer {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SocialConfiguration.class);

    @Inject
    private SocialUserConnectionRepository socialUserConnectionRepository;

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer connectionFactoryConfigurer, Environment environment) {
        // Google configuration
        String googleClientId = environment.getProperty("spring.social.google.clientId");
        String googleClientSecret = environment.getProperty("spring.social.google.clientSecret");
        if (googleClientId != null && googleClientSecret != null) {
            log.debug("Configuring GoogleConnectionFactory");
            connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(
                new GoogleConnectionFactory(
                    googleClientId,
                    googleClientSecret
                )
            );
        } else {
            log.error("Cannot configure GoogleConnectionFactory id or secret null");
        }

        // Facebook configuration
        String facebookClientId = environment.getProperty("spring.social.facebook.clientId");
        String facebookClientSecret = environment.getProperty("spring.social.facebook.clientSecret");
        if (facebookClientId != null && facebookClientSecret != null) {
            log.debug("Configuring FacebookConnectionFactory");
            connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(
                new FacebookConnectionFactory(
                    facebookClientId,
                    facebookClientSecret
                )
            );
        } else {
            log.error("Cannot configure FacebookConnectionFactory id or secret null");
        }

        // Twitter configuration
        String twitterClientId = environment.getProperty("spring.social.twitter.clientId");
        String twitterClientSecret = environment.getProperty("spring.social.twitter.clientSecret");
        if (twitterClientId != null && twitterClientSecret != null) {
            log.debug("Configuring TwitterConnectionFactory");
            connectionFactoryConfigurer.addConnectionFactory(
                new TwitterConnectionFactory(
                    twitterClientId,
                    twitterClientSecret
                )
            );
        } else {
            log.error("Cannot configure TwitterConnectionFactory id or secret null");
        }

        // jhipster-needle-add-social-connection-factory
    }

    @Override
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new AuthenticationNameUserIdSource();
    }

    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        return new CustomSocialUsersConnectionRepository(socialUserConnectionRepository, connectionFactoryLocator);
    }

    @Bean
    public SignInAdapter signInAdapter() {
        return new CustomSignInAdapter();
    }

    @Bean
    public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository, SignInAdapter signInAdapter) throws Exception {
        ProviderSignInController providerSignInController = new ProviderSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository, signInAdapter);
        providerSignInController.setSignUpUrl("/social/signup");
        return providerSignInController;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProviderSignInUtils getProviderSignInUtils(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator, UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository) {
        return new ProviderSignInUtils(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository);
    }
}
```

And my spring security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Inject
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Inject
    private TokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Inject
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/app/**/*.{js,html}")
            .antMatchers("/bower_components/**")
            .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
            .antMatchers("/content/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html")
            .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }

    // TODO unit test the security
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
        .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            // API part start
            ... antMatchers here
        .and()
            .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());

    }

    private JWTConfigurer securityConfigurerAdapter() {
        return new JWTConfigurer(tokenProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
        return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
    }
}
```